# Like Indicating Thoughts?

Tags: punctuation

> I get thoughts: like, **why may he go there**?

How may you, properly, and grammatically, indicate thoughts in maybe formal writing?

Comment: **may** indicates either future possibility, or current permission.  We'd say *Why would he go there?* if we were wondering about his motives.

Comment: There is no "grammatical" rule, strictly speaking, about how to punctuate reported speech, or one's own reported thoughts. These rules are merely conventions, governed by the author and/or editor in creative/literary works, and by the house stylesheet in journals. So you could write, *Sometimes I think to myself, why go there?* or *Sometimes I think to myself, "Why go there?"*

Comment: I think: I, may, see. I think: I, maybe, read, somewhere you, may, use, like, maybe, italics?

Comment: FYI: you are using far too many commas

Comment: Yes, italics are another conventional way of representing thought typographically; for example:    I thought to myself, *That is very strange!*